# How to create a new instance of variables in AngularJs so that their values would be independent of the original one?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to populate a field in a map with a another map from a list of pre-defined maps. I am using the following code to do so.

```
    $scope.parentMapList=[
              {
              fields:[]
              },
              {
              fields:[]
              }
    ];
    $scope.fieldsList=[
                {..},
                {..}
    ];
    $scope.addField = function(parentIndex,fieldIndex){

    $scope.parentMapList[parentIndex].fields.push($scope.fieldsList[index]);

};
```

And I am using the parentMapList as ng-models in the view. But whenever I edit one of the fields in one of the map. It automatically edits an another field of the same category in another map.

How do I decouple/remove the binding between them ? Is there a possibilty to create a new instance everytime I try to copy one of the fields into another in angularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var data= angular.copy($scope.parentMapList);`

Please refer the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) function.

Syntax is next:

> angular.copy(source,[destination])